# wordpress, search form using ajax

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am completely new to WordPress and my maximum is to create a plug-in with a function that displays "hello, I work." I have a search form by first and last name, and a working api written by me on another server on laravel.

My task is to make sure that when loading the page, the first 20 records taken from this api are loaded under the search form and actually carry out its work. In theory, this should not be difficult, but can anyone tell me how to do it right? Where to use the plugin and how to knock on my api. I know Js / ajax, but how to use them in a WordPress environment - no.

I would be very grateful for any tips